# Migrating ANTLR v2 grammar to ANTLR v4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr2

We have a grammar written for antlr V2 and I would like to migrate to antlr v4. Is there any migration Guide? I would also like to know modifications of existing V2 grammar so that we utilize v4 features well.

Comment: As far as I remember, V2 had some troubles with the variable lookahead. If you use constant lookahead in your grammar, the V4 parses a much broader class of languages (it's true even if you do use LL(*), but perhaps less significant).

Comment: The grammar file is at https://github.com/lcahlander/xqdoc-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/xqdoc/xquery/parser/jul2017/XQuery.g

Comment: I think that the versions are so different that you might as well start writing the v4 from scratch

Comment: I ended up doing that.  I still had problems, so I contracted Federico Tomassetti to complete the grammar for me.  The results will be posted at https://github.com/lcahlander/xqdoc

Comment: It has moved to the xqDoc account: https://github.com/xqdoc/xqdoc/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/org/xqdoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by writing a new Antlr 4 grammar file.  There is no good transform from Antlr 2 to Antlr 4.

Comment: The grammar files are at https://github.com/xqdoc/xqdoc/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/org/xqdoc

Answer (score 3):

nice to meet you again!

We recently migrated a set of large grammars to ANTLR 4 and wrote some lessons here: https://tomassetti.me/migrating-from-antlr2-to-antlr4/

Let me summarize the main points here.

## Why to migrate?

- ANTLR 4 has features that make grammars more concise and maintenable
- ANTLR2 supports only a few target platforms: Java, C#, and C++ while ANTLR4 supports many more

## ANTLR4 Features and Differences

- ANTLR4 accepts left-recursive grammars: this a big one, as it leads to far simpler and "less deep" grammars
- ANTLR4 parsers employ the adaptive LL(*) algorithm: no need for you to determine "k", which was never trivial to do
- ANTLR4 no longer builds an abstract syntax tree (AST). This one will impact your migration the most

## The process

1. Rewrite the grammar, one rule at a time, removing all AST construction logic if present.
2. Generate the parser and a visitor.
3. If the consuming code needs an AST, write a visitor that builds an AST from a parse tree.
4. If the ANTLR2 grammar included semantic actions, write a visitor that runs the actions, either from the parse tree or from the abstract syntax tree.

In the article we go into the details about translating the single options or the actions on tokens.

The core part is how to handle tree-rewriting rules, which are not present in ANTLR 4 anymore.

In practice you will need a library to define the AST, which you will obtain by simplifying the parse-tree produced by ANTLRv4. Now, in ANTLR v2 you used to do that in the grammar itself, while when using ANTLR v4 you will do that as a follow-up step. This is good, because you will have two simpler phases instead of one single convoluted grammar (good for maintenability and testability). However it would require you to write a little library to represent the AST.

In case you use the Java target you may be interested in using this open-source library to represent the AST: https://github.com/Strumenta/kolasu